# Changing a column value in pandas dataframe excluding the tail in group by

Tags: python, pandas

Let's take an example of a python dataframe.

**ID Age Bp**

1  22    1

1  22    1

1  22    0

1  22    1

2  21    0

2  21    1

2  21    0

In the above code, the last n series for column BP (lets consider n to be 2) with group by ID should be excluded and the rest of the BP should be changed to 0. I have tried it with tail but it does not work.

It should look like this.

**ID Age BP**

1 22 0

1 22 0

1 22 0

1 22 1

2 21 0

2 21 1

2 21 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) with `ascending=False` for counter from back per groups and assign `0` with [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
n = 2
mask = df.groupby('ID').cumcount(ascending=False) < n
df['Bp'] = np.where(mask, df['Bp'], 0)
```

Alternatives:

```
df.loc[~mask, 'Bp'] = 0
df['Bp'] = df['Bp'].where(mask, 0)
```

---

```
print (df)
   ID  Age  Bp
0   1   22   0
1   1   22   0
2   1   22   0
3   1   22   1
4   2   21   0
5   2   21   1
6   2   21   0
```

Details:

```
print (df.groupby('ID').cumcount(ascending=False))
0    3
1    2
2    1
3    0
4    2
5    1
6    0
dtype: int64

print (mask)
0    False
1    False
2     True
3     True
4    False
5     True
6     True
dtype: bool
```